# How to join a table when the to be joined table is a variable in column

Tags: sql

I have a table called `Table1`.

The table contains columns like:

- The `sourceID` (`ID` of the join)
- The `sourceTable` (the table to be joined table, this is variable)

My query:

```
SELECT T.Category, J.Tariff
FROM Table1 as T
INNER JOIN T.SourceTable J ---- This needs to be changed
ON T.sourceID = J.id
```

Is this possible?

Basically the source table can be different for every row

Comment: Ref: [Check this out](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... it would be really helpful to know what concrete **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Can you post some sample data and table structures?  Based on your description it seems like you have a separate table for each `id`, if so that design seems very flawed.

Comment: Is the range of other table names known?

Comment: The range of the other table names is not known.

Answer (score 0):

Table names cannot be dynamic in an SQL Query. You have to find a different way to do this. 
Use a `Stored Procedure` and/or EXEC().

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that's generally a bad idea. Even if possible, it basically prevents the optimiser from doing much (which can cause the query to slow down a lot).

I suggest changing your database design to make what you're trying to do easier (think having a base table which the tables you want to join on have a 1-to-1 mapping to) rather than trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union, and filter by the column with the table pointer. Something like this:

```
SELECT T.Category, J.Tariff
FROM Table1 as T
INNER JOIN T.SourceTable1 J ON T.sourceID = J.id
where T.sourceTable = '1'
union
SELECT T.Category, J.Tariff
FROM Table1 as T
INNER JOIN T.SourceTable2 J ON T.sourceID = J.id
where T.sourceTable = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle it's possible using left joins, but only if you have a fixed set of lookup tables (otherwise, you'll need to build your SQL statement dynamically):

```
SELECT T.Category, coalesce(source1.tariff, source2.tariff) as tariff
FROM Table1 as T
LEFT OUTER JOIN T.source1 
  ON T.sourceID = source1.id and t.sourcetable = 'source1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN T.source2 
  ON T.sourceID = source2.id and t.sourcetable = 'source2'
```

but as mentioned in the other answers, that's usually a sign that your database design is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

1) Create a `VIEW` with all source tables:

```
CREATE VIEW source_tables AS
(SELECT 'table_1' as table_name,
        id,
        value
 FROM table_1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'table_2' as table_name,
        id,
        value
 FROM table_2
 UNION ALL
 ..........
 SELECT 'table_n' as table_name,
        id,
        value
 FROM table_n);
```

2) Use the `VIEW` to get the values from source table:

```
SELECT T.category, S.value
FROM base_table as T
JOIN source_tables S ON T.sourceID = S.id AND T.SourceTable = S.table_name
```